# `google-authenticator-libpam` and yocto

Tags: yocto, pam, google-authenticator

I'm using OpenBMC. I want to add `google-authenticator-libpam` package. But I don't know how can I notify yocto to compile and add `meta-security/recipes-security/google-authenticator-libpam` to image as a PAM module. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

---

---Update---

I moved `google-authenticator-libpam` package (its directory) from `meta-security/recipes-security/` to `meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-security` and it's visible to bitbake by appending its name to `OBMC_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL` variable currently (it will append to `CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL` variable finally).

How can I make `meta-security` recipes visible to bitbake (same as recipes of `meta-openembedded/meta-oe/`)?

Comment: What layers are in your `build/conf/bblayers.conf`?

Comment: @Johnb You're right. Thanks a lot. `meta-security` layer does not available in layers list. Although, I had added it in `bblayers.conf.sample` of my layer. It seems that I need a `clean`/`cleansstate` command.